# Switchport negotiation between trunk and dynamic desirable

Tags: trunk, switchport

If two switches are connected, one with switchport mode trunk and the other with switchport mode dynamic desirable, will both switches form an operational trunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If two switches are connected, one with `switchport mode trunk` and the
>   other with `switchport mode dynamic desirable`, will both switches form
>   an operational trunk?

Yes, the switchports will form a trunk as `switchport mode trunk` does not disable DTP.

A switchport configured with `switchport mode dynamic auto` will also negotiate as a trunk if the connected switchport is configured with `switchport mode trunk`.

Comment: In addition, if two switches with switchport mode dynamic desirable are connected to each other, the switches will also form a trunk. The list is: `Trunk + Trunk = Trunk`
`Trunk + Des = Trunk`
`Trunk + Auto = Trunk`
`Des + Des = Trunk`
`Des + Auto = Trunk`
`Auto + Auto = Access`
`Any + Access = Access`
`nonnegotiate + Trunk = Trunk`
`nonnegotiate + nonnegotiate = Trunk`

Default is dynamic auto.